# Как получить все разрешения видео на youtube?

Tags: python, youtube

Мне надо чтобы когда я отправлял ссылку мне возвращало список разрешений как тут:

```
['114p','240p','360p','480p','720p','1080p']
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Answer (score 0):

У вас конкретный вопрос? На каком языке вы пишете?
Если на Python, то вот ответ:

```py
from pytube import YouTube
resolutions = []
url = 'Введите ссылку здесь' #ссылка тут
yt = YouTube(url)
for i in yt.streams: resolutions.append(str(i.resolution)) # собирает информацию
print(resolutions) # вывод на экран
```